# volley code onResponse() and onErrorResponse() are not called

Tags: android, android-volley

Here is my volley code, but onResponse() as well as onErrorResponse() are not called. The Log lines are never printed as these metods are skipped. But the last log line appears in logcat and the jsObjRequest is always null.

```
String url = "A valid url";
JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, 
    url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Log.e("onResponse",""+response);
    }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
     @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e("onErrorResponse", "" + error);
    }
    });
   Log.e("jsObjRequest",  "" + jsObjRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enqueue your request:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

String url = "A valid url";
JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, 
url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Log.e("onResponse",""+response);
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
       Log.e("onErrorResponse", "" + error);
    }
});
Log.e("jsObjRequest",  "" + jsObjRequest);

queue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

see this: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html

Answer (score 0):

You should add your request to a RequestQueue. In your situation simply add these 2 lines of code below yours, it will work then.

```
RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
rQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this issue i use HTTPS and its working very well now